# Rails : How can I get boolean data from radio button?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have DB tables 'question', 'answer'.(Those two tables has been related by has_many and belongs_to, and nested_form relationship.)

And there is user_answer(boolean, default 'false') column in answer table.

I want to make it like this.

1. If user check the radio button, user_answer change to 'true' value.
2. Then I'll compare another value in correct column in answer table,
3. and finally I'll save the result in is_correct column in question table.

But I don't know how can I do. This is input form.

```
<h1><%= @survey.name %></h1>
 <%= form_tag({:controller => "surveys", :action => "grading"}) do %>
  <ol class="questions">
   <% @survey.questions.each do |question| %>
   <li>
   <strong><%= question.content %></strong>
    <ol class="checkbox">
     <% question.answers.each do |answer| %>
       <%= radio_button_tag(answer.user_answer) %>
       <%= label("answer_".concat(answer.id.to_s).to_sym, answer.content) %>
     <% end %>
     </ol>
     <hr />
   </li>
   <% end %>
  </ol>

  <div><%= submit_tag("Submit", :class => "submit") %></div>
```

Of course, there is an error. radio_button_tag need 2 parameters. But I don't know how can I do. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a constant in your Model Such as:

```
STATUS = [['active', true], ['Inactive', false]]
```

and use options for select in your views.

```
<%= f.select :status, options_for_select(User::STATUS) %>
```

Useful resources:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/radio_button_tag

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select

Comment: Thanks Sami. But unfortunately I just finished rails tutorial, so I couldn't realize your answer 100%. I just want to save true if radio button checked, to 'answer.user_answer'. Would you please tell me more detailed?

Comment: In which column and in which table you are saving the value.

Comment: Add a boolean type column/field to your table where you want to save the result. then do something like this for your radio button

<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
<div>
<%= f.label :your-field-name, "Yes", :value => "true"  %>
<%= f.radio_button :your-field-name, true %>
<%= f.label :your-field-name, "No", :value => "false" %>
<%= f.radio_button :your-field-name, false, :checked => true %>
</div>
<% end %>